# change width according to child element(set it to max-witdh)

Tags: html, css

For following html the value of H3 tag is dynamically loaded . I want that when h3 is long as in the following case div with class login-box left takes the value of max-with or atleast increase the width value . But it's still taking min-value and brreaking the design

```
  <div class="login-box left" style="min-width: 230px; max-width:300px">
  <div class="login-box-title" style="width:auto">
  <h3>Engångslösenordsinloggning</h3>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want. i removed the min-width and added `display:inline-block;`

```
<div class="login-box left" style="display: inline-block; max-width:300px">
 <div class="login-box-title" style="width:auto">
 <h3>Engångslösenordsinloggning</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: I need one more help . When there is space in content of h3 in that case it goes to another line in that case I don't want to disturb existing layout but in case of  words when there is no width I want to extend width

Comment: then se the css `white-space: nowrap;` to the h3

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="login-box left" style="min-width: 230px; display:inline-block;">
    <div class="login-box-title" style="width:auto">
        <h3>Engångslösenordsinloggning</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.